# Ubuntu 15.10 core files not found although core_pattern looks ok

Tags: 15.10, apport, ulimit

On Ubuntu 15.10 I can not find the core files dumped by my program.
`ulimit` is set to `unlimited`.
After uninstalling the `apport` service, the `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` file only contains `core` which should just create a file called `core` in the same directory of my failing executable. Unfortunately that's not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution was to set 
    `ulimit -c unlimited`

Here is my full solution that puts all the core files in /tmp/cores with an explicit name for those files:

```
sudo apt-get remove apport
ulimit -u unlimited
sudo bash -c 'echo "* hard core unlimited" >> /etc/security/limits.conf'
sudo bash -c 'echo "* soft core unlimited" >> /etc/security/limits.conf'
sudo bash -c 'echo "kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/cores/core.%e.%p.%h.%t" >> /etc/sysctl.conf'
sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Then you need to logout or reboot to make it all work.